# Create sub directories within django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a simple website that contains entries (blog posts) organized in the url by example.com/blog/category_id/post_id

However what I'm currently doing only resolves example.com/blog/category_id. Can someone show me how to change the code to make it:

1. List all blog posts when going to example.com/blog
2. List all blog posts of a particular category when going to example.com/blog/category_id
3. List a particular blog post when going to example.com/blog/category_id/post_id

Thank you!

If I need to provide more information please let me know.

blog.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "blog"
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('<int:welcome_id>/', views.welcome_detail, name='welcome_detail'),
        path('blog/<int:category_id>/', views.category, name="category"),
        path('blog/<int:category_id>/<int:blog_id>/', views.category, views.blog_post_detail, name="blog_detail"),
        ]
```

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class WelcomePage(models.Model):
    greeting_text = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
  
    def most_recently_published(self):
        return Status.objects.order_by('id')[0]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.greeting_text


class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

    def get_categories(self):
        return Status.objects.order_by('id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blog_text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def most_recently_published(self):
        return Status.objects.order_by('id')[:5]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from .models import WelcomePage, BlogPost, Categories

def index(request):
    latest_welcome_message = WelcomePage.objects.order_by('id')
    latest_blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('id')
    categories = Categories.objects.order_by('id')
    template = loader.get_template('blog/index.html')
    context = {'latest_welcome_message' : latest_welcome_message, 'latest_blog_posts' : latest_blog_posts, "categories" : categories}
        
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)

def welcome_detail(request, welcome_id):
    try:
        welcome_message = WelcomePage.objects.get(pk=welcome_id)
    except WelcomePage.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'welcome_message':welcome_message})

def category(request, category_id):
    try:
        blogs_of_category = BlogPost.objects.get(categories=category_id)
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Blog does not exist")
    return render(request, "blog/category.html", {"category":blogs_of_category})

def blog_post_detail(request, blog_id):
    try:
        blog_post_detail = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Blog does not exist")
    return render(request, "blog/blogdetail.html", {"blog":blog_post_detail})
```

When I try to visit example.com/blog/1/1/ I get the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://your.program.sucks/blog/1/0/

Django Version: 2.2.24
Python Version: 3.5.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/virtualenvpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/virtualenvpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/virtualenvpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /blog/1/0/
Exception Value: blog_post_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_id'
```

Comment: try to remove `views.category` from the last urlpattern

Comment: @Marat I can see the example.com/blog/1 now, that reports success

Comment: Your url pattern for categories I would change to `/category/<int:category_id>` and for blog post `/blog/<int:blog_id>` The way you have two parameters at the moment for the detail view makes no sense. You don't even use the `category_id` in the last url pattern.

Comment: @Limecat The thing is that a blog contains a category, and I want to list out all blog posts of a particular category. As well as being able to list out all blog posts as a whole. As well as being able to show a specific blog post.

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it in console/terminal? I think you should get error because in last `path()` you have both `views.category` and `views.blog_post_detail` - and this can make problems. Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas thanks for your input I was able to resolve the error on my own!

Comment: now I see you need `category_id` in `def blog_post_detail(request, category_id, blog_id):`

Comment: @sololuvr yes, I understand what you want. List all blogposts doesn't need a pk, list of all blogposts of a category needs the pk of the category, and viewing a particular blogpost needs the pk of the blogpost. Why do you need the category pk to show the detail view of a blogpost? Your url path has two pk's and you're not capturing both, you're only capturing the blogpost pk. If the path is `<int:pk_1>/<int:pk_2>/` then your function needs a signature of `def function(request, pk_1, pk_2):` Otherwise what's the point of having the redundant pk?